# Llamada a una función miembro create () en null Error: se ha producido un error interno. CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9

Tags: cakephp

> Unable to add your post. Call to a member function create() on null
>   Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

```
Stack Trace
[internal function] → PagesController->fullClient(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 491 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(PagesController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(PagesController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 117 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

---

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'fullClient', 'full_client'));
```

---

PagesController.php

```
public function fullClient(){
         $this->Cliente->find('all');
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
      if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Cliente->create();
            if ($this->Cliente->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__("gola"));
                return $this->request->data;
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
```

---

Cliente.php(Modelo)

```
class Cliente extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'empresa' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'cliente' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'direccion' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'telefono' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'informacion' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'horario' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
```

---

full_client.ctp(Vista)

```
<?php


echo $this->Form->create('Cliente');
echo $this->Form->input('empresa', array('label' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Cual es el nombre de tu empresa'));
  echo $this->Form->input('cliente');
   echo $this->Form->input('direccion');
    echo $this->Form->input('telefono');

    echo $this->Form->input('informacion');

    echo $this->Form->input('horario');

    echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');


    ?>
```

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, **por favor si puede pase el titulo de su pregunta a español** ya que este no es un sitio en ingles muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de CakePHP utilizas?

Comment: El titulo traducido es:  Llamada a una función miembro create () en null Error: se ha producido un error interno.

la version es la 2

Comment: click aquí para editar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/148905/edit

Comment: Por lo general me pasa cuando no he cargado el modelo, utilizaste `$this->loadModel('Modelo')`?, el título no es el poblema, porque ese es el error que te lanza, creo que la pregunta se podría mejorar poniendo un título que describa el problema y poniendo tu código no solo el stack trace del error, te sugiero terminar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), y revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ya subi el codigo

Comment: todo lo que pones en los comentarios respecto al fallo que te ocurre agregalos pero a la pregunta original para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Listo, creo que lo hice.

Comment: Intentaste cargar el modelo con `$this->loadModel('Cliente')`?

Comment: KacosPro, thanks con eso dio, pero me gusta saber el porque de las cosas, por que era necesario eso? es que tenia un ejemplo en el que no use eso y funciono.

Comment: Ahorita te pongo una respuesta con la explicación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De la documentación:

> Cuando un modelo es definido, este puede ser accedido desde tu Controllador. CakePHP automaticamente hará el modelo accesible cuando su nombre coincide con el del controlador.

Osea para `ClientesController` CakePHP hará accesible al modelo mediante `$this->Cliente`.

Como tu quieres acceder desde otro controlador tienes que cargar el modelo "a mano" con [`$this->loadModel()`](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::loadModel), de esta manera

```
$this->loadModel('Cliente');
```

Comment: A ya, el que te mencionaba era PostController y el modal era Post. por eso no necesitaba esa linea, gracias.

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió la respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada. Puedes encontrar mas información en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Creo que ya la acepte la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias y bienvenido! Y te animo a que sigas participando en el sitio!